# Convert keras model from python3.6. to 3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have a model trained in keras with python 3.6 and having a raspbian with python 3.5.

When you load a model (or at least my model) trained with python 3.6 into python 3.6 you get an exception:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The problem is that for different reasons I can't change training platform to 3.5 or RPi to 3.6, so I have to convert the model.h5.

Is there a way to convert the h5 to something intermediate and then convert from the intermediate to h5 in the other platform?

The error rise when I call load_module

The problem is that for different reasons I can't change training platform to 3.5 or RPi to 3.6, so I have to convert de model.h5.

Is there a way to convert th h5 to something intermediate and then convert from the intermediate to h5 in the other platform?

```
load_model("model1527371035.h5")    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 270, in load_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 347, in model_from_config
    return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 144, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 1412, in from_config
    model.add(layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 497, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 619, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 685, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "<ipython-input-11-b85ceb3c6761>", line 64, in <lambda>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The model looks like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.0 - 0.5, input_shape=(84, 84, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(36,(5,5), strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(40))
model.add(Dropout(dropout))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam",metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
```

Comment: Can you provide context for the error? Which file, code that is causing etc?

Comment: Load_module("model.h5") It works in one platform an not in the other.

Comment: Looks like an error in a `Lambda` layer of your model, can you post a snippet of the model?

Comment: Yes @nuric it is...  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9595

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, looking at the comment with the ongoing [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9595), the current workaround looks like just saving and loading weights:

```
model.save_weights(filename)
# you have to rebuild model again
model.load_weights(filename)
```

This case the saved file would not contain the architecture and you have to rebuild it every time. This isn't costly so it shouldn't be a problem.

EDIT: perhaps this only affects `Lambda` layers, it might be a simple [custom layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) avoids this issue:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):
   def call(self, x):
     return x / 255.0 - 0.5
```

Comment: Yes look like, I'm going to redefine de model and then load weights to check if it works.

Comment: Just encapsulate it in a function like `build_model()` which returns that particular construction, then save load weights etc.

Comment: Lambda functions are not liked when you move the model, and use to get a warning about you cant train, but when you change from 3.6 to 3.5 it simply crash. I can extract normalization outside of the model. Bat anyway saving and loading the weights is enough no me.

Comment: If I save the weights and biases on python 3.6 is it possible to load them on python 2.7?